# C programming program only printing the first value in my variable

Tags: c

Program only displaying the 32 for when I have it print "NewTemp"
NewTemp = 32 + input * 180/100;  this part seems like the main problem

```
#include <stdio.h>

float celsius(float input) {
    float NewTemp;
    **NewTemp = 32 + input * 180/100; 
    printf("Please enter the temperature value to convert to fahrenheit\n");
    scanf("%f", &input);
    printf("The temperature in celsius is: %f\n", NewTemp);

    return NewTemp;

}

int main(void){
 float CelToFahren, input;
    CelToFahren = celsius(input);
}
```

Comment: C is a procedural language - lines execute one after the other. Your line starting `NewTemp` does not define a formula; it performs the steps of computing a value based on a formula.  (Languages where this defines a formula are generally called "functional languages").

Comment: `NewTemp` is not a pointer to a pointer to a float, so `**NewTemp` is utter nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the math before you read the input. You need to do it the other way around.

Also, there's no reason to pass a meaningless and uninitialized value to the `celsius` function.

Lastly, `180/100` is 1 remainder 80 because when you divide two integers, you get integer division. You can use `180.0/100.0`.

Basically, you need to learn C.

Comment: The `180` is fine because `input` is a float

Comment: Right, but next time he'll write `32 + input * (180/100)` and his code will break.

Comment: I realized why parenthesis would break the code but im still lost on the "Also, there's no reason to pass a meaningless and uninitialized value to the celsius function.
"

Comment: The `celsius` function does not need a value passed to it. And your `main` function passes it the value of `input`, which you never set to anything in particular. So you are passing the function garbage, which it ignores.

Comment: Oh, i see so I would only be passing values into it if I multiple functions working and passing?