# Floating point math in c getting random numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, division

I'm doing a exercise from C primer plus that involves working with floats, I can't get the result to also be a float. I got it to read in the input fine (as far as I can tell) but the problem must be in the formula line. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   float inp1, inp2;
   float result;

   result = (inp1 - inp2) / (inp1 * inp2); /* formula */

   printf("enter two values\n");
   scanf("%f %f", &inp1, &inp2);

   printf("(%.3f - %.3f) / (%.3f * %.3f)\n", inp1, inp2, inp1, inp2);
   printf("%f\n", result);
}
```

The output is giving some random number (I don't know what it's called), for example with an input of 1.255 and 1.023 I get an output of 2656044210243861500000000000000000000.000000 or something similar. The second to last printf displays the input correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

I've tried this, but I don't really get how cast operators work.

`result = ((float)inp1 - (float)inp2) / ((float)inp1 * (float)inp2); //formula`

and

```
result = (float)(inp1 - inp2) / (inp1 * inp2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = (inp1 - inp2) / (inp1 * inp2); /* formula */

printf("enter two values\n");
scanf("%f %f", &inp1, &inp2);
```

Well, what about putting `scanf` call before `result = ...;` assignment statement?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is it because the computer calculates the result before the input is taken in?

Comment: @Zak. computer programs typically run from top to bottom, not calculate values according to predefined formulas

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: not by necessity (XSLT does not), but certainly true for C -- inside functions. (When putting a function before `main`, the *function* certainly does not run "first".)

Comment: @Zak: the computation uses the *current* values of `inp1` and `inp2`. At the time you calculate `result`, these values are undefined. So calculate the value of result *after* you gave them defined values (or let the user give them such values using `scanf(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

```
result = (inp1 - inp2) / (inp1 * inp2); /* formula */

printf("enter two values\n");
scanf("%f %f", &inp1, &inp2);
```

That's not how things work in a language like C; you don't define a *formula* for `result` that's automatically computed when you read your inputs.  Rather, you first read your inputs, and then you *compute* the value and *assign* it to `result`:

```
printf("enter two values\n");
scanf("%f %f", &inp1, &inp2);

result = (inp1 - inp2) / (inp1 * inp2); /* computation and assignment */
```

C is an imperative language, meaning you have to explicitly list out the instructions for it to follow, including those for any mathematical computations.

Comment: "C is an imperative language" .. the same error as in the recent http://stackoverflow.com/q/26027585/2564301. I wonder if both posters are doing the same course, or have a similar programming history. What declarative language could have come before?

Answer (score 1):

The analogy of math formulas in programming languages is *functions* (without side effects). That way, you can define formulas before the code itself. For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float formula(float inp1, float inp2)
{
  return (inp1 - inp2) / (inp1 * inp2);
}

int main(void)
{
   float inp1, inp2;

   printf("enter two values\n");
   scanf("%f %f", &inp1, &inp2);

   printf("(%.3f - %.3f) / (%.3f * %.3f)\n", inp1, inp2, inp1, inp2);
   printf("%f\n", formula(inp1, inp2));
   return 0;
}
```